# Regression on mean

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, mean, standard-deviation

Problem: My Dataset doesn't contain actual data, but it contains only mean and standard deviation of the features. And also those data(mean and standard deviation) are taken at equal intervals of time (5-minutes) and those mean and standard deviation are itself cumulative in nature.

Dataset:

Time    Mean std-dev

T1  -    Mean1    Std-dev1

T2  -    Mean2    Std-dev2

.....

Tn  - Mean_n  std-dev_n

(Please note that these data are itself cumulative, I also don't know the distribution of data)

Now I want to build a predictive model based on the data, I'm very much confused about applying regression on these data. Whether any data pre-processing techniques available? Or any other way I could make some assumptions and go forward and apply regression techniques on those data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what these "standard deviations" are?  If they are standard deviations of sets of responses at each time, then do you have the counts of those responses?  Could you clarify what "cumulative in nature" might mean?  What exactly are you trying to predict with your model--individual data, means, standard deviations, trends, something else?

Comment: They are standard deviations of responses at each time, yes I have the count of the responses. Basically, I trying to predict the throughput of the system. The Mean is the latencies of the data transfer, for every 5 minutes, and std-dev is for the same. Suppose the system takes 5.6 milliseconds (mean) to transfer 60k objects in the first time interval, and  3 milliseconds (mean) to transfer 10k objects in the second time interval. My dataset has the mean 5.6 ms in the first time interval t1, and thereafter it contains the cumulative mean

Comment: (for example the mean recorded in the time interval t2, is actually the mean for the time interval ( t1 + t2 )) and the same applies for the standard deviation